# ending "+" prompt in R

Tags: r, r-faq

I'm fairly new to R and I made a type-o while entering some code and now instead of getting the ">" prompt I get a "+" prompt. I appear to be stuck in some kind of function that is looking for input, but I can't seem to get out of it. I figure that there must be a better way to fix this problem then closing R and rerunning my script but I haven't been able to find anything on google (likely because I don't know the right search terms).

Thanks for your help, sorry it's a trivial question

The code I entered was as follows:

```
> fit = lm(x~`y)
+ fit = lm(x~y)
+ fit
+ summary(fit)
+ 
+ 
+ end
+ ;
+ break
+ )
+ 
+ 
+ 
+           
+      
+ quit()
+ 
+ quit
+ break()
+ abline(b0hat,b1hat)
+ return(null)
+
```

Comment: Did you try using the Esc key?

Comment: After reformatting the cause is clearer to me. That unmatched backtick in the first line means the parser is waiting for a match before it evaluates anything.

Comment: @A5C1D2H2I1M1N2O1R2T1 The `Esc` key only works if one is in the console, it doesn't if one is in the script editor

Answer (score 96, accepted):

It depends on how you’re running R.

In the terminal, the “normal” way is <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> – the “cancel” key combination.

In the graphical R application and in RStudio, it’s <kbd>Escape</kbd>.

Comment: I'm running R 3.0.1 in the Console on a Mac, and the Excape key seemed to do the trick

Comment: @user6179 That’s odd, it doesn’t work for me, and on the console it *shouldn’t* work.

Comment: @javadba Uhm, that’s very weird. What console are you using?

Comment: It was the console for R on El Capitan.

Comment: One has to click on the console first for `Escape` to work. Is there any shortcut to make it work when one is in the script editor?

Comment: @Julien I don’t use RStudio but you can use Ctrl-2 to move focus to the console, and Ctrl-1 to move focus back to the code editor afterwards.

Comment: I already know this shortcut, I want something more direct

Answer (score 4):

IShouldBuyABoat was right the problem was that I accidentally included a back tick, this caused the parser to require a second back tick to close the string before evaluating the string or returning the proper prompt.

I used Escape key as suggested by Konrad Rudolph, although I was not in R studio and this returned the prompt.

Thanks for all the help, and sorry I didn't post my answer earlier. This is my first question and I didn't realize that I was supposed to do that.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem when "copy/pasting" large quantities of text into the R prompt. I would see a dangling "+" at the end. However, when individually selecting blocks of executable code and pasting sequentially, the "+" would not appear. I ended up loading the entire file in the terminal to solve the problem:

```
source("myfile_with_lots_of_text.r")
```

Answer (score -1):

If you are using terminal you can quit using q()

Comment: This won't work in this case. `q()` is no different than `quit()`, which OP demonstrated in the question.

Answer (score -2):

I am using RStudio 3.3.1  and had a the same problem. Press Escape key for worked. Please try this and let me know if I  can help more...

Comment: Yes, this was already introduced in the accepted answer. What did your answer add to the already existing answers?