# How to forcefully exit a multi-line command in R

Tags: r

I accidentally entered an incomplete command into my R session.

`boxplot(logminutevol~dmnckad, main=Dominick's Ad)`

R now thinks everything I enter is part of a multi-line command. I tried typing several lines to force an error but R just gives me more lines to type. I also can't save the session to restart because R think's I'm in the middle of a command. How do I forcefully exit this multi-line command mode without losing my workspace?

Comment: `Escape` or `Control-C` depending on your OS.

Comment: for what it's worth your ultimate problem is the single-quote/apostrophe in the `main` argument: to avoid this in the future, use `main="Dominick's Ad"`

Comment: @BenBolker this question and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18803354/ending-prompt-in-r) are very different. Esc / ctrl + c exits *one* command (the one executing), it does not stop *all* lines of commands (which I think is what's meant by multi-line). I just accidentally ran ~1000 lines of code due to a single missing `"`. I learned the hard way

Comment: @BenBolker I tapped `Esc` frantically for five min until it was done, but a neat way of stopping *all executed lines* would have been far less stressful

Comment: @stevec, Ctrl-C does work for the particular example this user gave.  It would be fine to post a new question (linking to this one and emphasizing the difference so it doesn't get closed as a duplicate)

Comment: @BenBolker [done](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61079751/how-to-stop-all-multiple-executed-lines-of-code-commands-in-r-in-one-go)

Answer (score 1):

I pressed the red stop button below R's menu bar which got me back to the command line.

Comment: that is another option, although `ESC/Ctrl-C` are more general (existence of "stop" buttons and their placement will depend on what graphical interface you're using)