# How to stop all (multiple) executed lines of code / commands in R in one go?

Tags: r, rstudio

Suppose we run multiple lines of R code, how can we stop ***all*** lines of code in on go?

#### Example

If the following 3 lines of code are copy/pasted into the R console in RStudio and we press enter, this will take 3 <kbd>Esc</kbd> or <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>c</kbd> to stop (one press for each command). Alternatively, pressing the red `Stop` button in the RStudio gui also must be done three times (once per command)

```
Sys.sleep(10)
Sys.sleep(10)
Sys.sleep(10)
```

How can we stop ***all*** lines of R code from executing with one action?

#### What I know so far

- For some reason, when running R from terminal, a single <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>c</kbd> is enough to stop *all* lines of code
- The only solutions I have for stopping all lines of code in RStudio are to tap <kbd>Esc</kbd> or <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>c</kbd> continuously until all lines have been cancelled (inconvenient to say the least), or, to abort the R session (typically undesirable)
- There's a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22133577/how-to-forcefully-exit-a-multi-line-command-in-r) which [differs in that it's not multiple commands over multiple lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22133577/how-to-forcefully-exit-a-multi-line-command-in-r?noredirect=1#comment108057279_22133577)

Comment: Did you ever find a solution? Very frustrating aspect of R

Comment: @CoolGuyHasChillDay no, I never found a solution.