# Escape readLines() function in RStudio

Tags: r, console, rstudio

Because of the work I do with R, I need to use the `readline()` function to enter text. The problem comes when sometimes, instead of writting `readline()` I run `readLines()` accidentally (due to autocomplete or whatever reason).

Once I have run `readLines()`, there is nothing I can do to escape the function. I can keep on writing but can't recover a prompt in the console (can't run any code) as I do not know how to close the `readLines()` function call. Any clues?

Note that this problem only happens in RStudio (and, according to Matt in the comments, Visual Studio).

[image]

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18803354/ending-prompt-in-r

Comment: @Matt I had tried those before and to now avail! I dont know what is going on

Comment: If you're using a normal terminal (not RStudio) then **ctrl + c** can be used to interrupt any process. The RStudio console is occasionally more frustrating. **esc** should stop most processes, but it doesn't always work. Sometimes it helps to press **esc** more than once, sometimes it doesn't. In such cases I usually just restart R with **cmd + shift + F10** (Mac, not sure if it's the same for PC).

Comment: @gersht That is what I do at the moment (i use RStudio) but I am surprised there is no command to exist the `readLines()` prompt.

Comment: Maybe not the best way, but you could always `debug(readLines)`. Then if you do end up calling `readLines` just type `Q` to exit back to `>`.

Comment: this strikes me as a bug/infelicity in RStudio's interface.  In a Unix R console, ctrl-D (="end-of-file") also works.  I would raise this question on an RStudio forum. (I think you should edit your question to clarify/emphasize that this is in RStudio ...)

Comment: @BenBolker For what it is worth, this issue happened for me in MS Visual Studio as well.

Answer (score 1):

Not a perfect fix, but you can use `debug()`. Anytime you do end up calling `readLines()` by accident, you can just exit `browse[2]` by typing `Q`.

```
debug(readLines)
readline()
asdf
```

`[1] "asdf"`

```
readLines()
debugging in: readLines()
debug: {
    if (is.character(con)) {
        con <- file(con, "r")
        on.exit(close(con))
    }
    .Internal(readLines(con, n, ok, warn, encoding, skipNul))
}
```

`Browse[2]> Q`

```
readline()
asdf
```

`[1] "asdf"`