# Is there any shortcut to interrupt code that ends with + in RStudio without the action "going to console + Escape"

Tags: r, rstudio, keyboard-shortcuts

If the following code is run from the script editor in RStudio, there is a `+` sign (that indicates that it must be completed).

How to cancel it without going to the console + pressing <kbd>Escape</kbd>?

```r
mean(1 # A parenthesis is missing on purpose
```

[image]

I want a direct shortcut, not the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>2</kbd> (going to the console) and <kbd>Esc</kbd>.

The [ending "+" prompt in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18803354/ending-prompt-in-r/18803911?noredirect=1#comment136837993_18803911) thread didn't help

Comment: AFAIK, there is no other way to escape out without hitting `Esc`.